# Twig filter on Webform Computed Twig element

Tags: webforms

I have a webform where I am gathering information on multiple questions (q1, q2) using the Image Select input type where each option has a value of 0,1,2,3 or 4.

I then use a Computed Twig Element element to perform a calculation on those modules:

```
{{data.q1 + data.q2}}
```

The value calculates correctly, but also gives an error:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in __TwigTemplate_cd3a9ebc1b3926be2ad8645d59045ec00f6b94edddb5e60df6140411f5dece1d->doDisplay() (line 39 of /tmp/rolling/e1555e9/twig/62f1d500a7ac1___string_template__101327_Sz_1wKa-YlFg9227-b5dQAz4B/hK-aBjEvfXL8MqrWdNU0pXNOjmLq_uceb--VyGVgJEg.php)
```

I wondered if this is because the value from the Image Select element is a string instead of an integer and hoped I could fix it by using a Twig conversion filter to convert it to an integer:

```
{{data.q1|integer + data.q2|integer}}
```

However, when I try to add that filter, it gives me the error:

```
Computed value/markup is not valid.
- Unknown "integer" filter in
"__string_template__791a...."
at line 1.
```

Any ideas on how to remove that error or additional troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Is there a reason you convert only one of the values to integer?

Comment: Thank you @cilefen - that was a mistake in the question, it should be both converted to an integer:
`{{data.q1|integer + data.q2|integer}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if all of Drupal's Twig extensions are available in the Webform context. Try this:

```
{{data.q1|number_format + data.q2|number_format}}
```

Comment: That did it - thank you so much, I really appreciate it!